# how to set the audio file sample rate for watson text to speech in node-red

Tags: text-to-speech, ibm-watson, node-red

watson text to speech accepts extra parameters such as the sampling (default is 44khz)

see https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/text-to-speech/api/v1/#synthesize_audio for options such as this one

```
(...)
audio/l16;rate=rate 
(You can optionally specify endianness=big-endian 
or endianness=little-endian; the default is little endian.) 
(...)
```

but I can't see a way to set these options in node red

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Node-red, doesn't have the option, because you need to add in your `cURL`.

As you can see, you can use `Accept` or `accept` query parameter header to specify the audio format.

[image]

For example:

```
curl -X POST -u "{username}":"{password}"
--header "Content-Type: application/json"
--header "Accept: audio/l16;endianness=big-endian"
--data "{\"text\":\"Hello world\"}"
--output hello_world.wav
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?voice=en-US_AllisonVoice"
```

- See the Official [Text to Speech v1 API Explorer](https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/text-to-speech-v1#!/synthesize/postSynthesize).

Answer (score 1):

Please raise this as an improvement request on the github repo for the nodes, we can continue the discussion there. No promises, but I am open to accepting a pull request, if done right.

Comment: thanks. I've noticed that there's already a partial implementation up there in the repo. I will just wait for it to be complete. I am also studying, maybe I can try to help too.